# How to remove partially installed sdk in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to install pie and nougat in android studio.But due to low disk space it partially installed nougat.Due to low disk space ,I want to uninstall nougat completely how can I do this?

Comment: Remove anything in Android SDK == Untick anything in Android SDK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To uninstall an SDK, you can use the `sdkmanager --uninstall [packages]` command, replacing `[packages]` with the name of the SDK. For example:

`$ ./Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-24"`

would uninstall the Nougat SDK.

Alternatively, you can delete the corresponding folder on your machine without causing issues. In this case, the folder would be:

`$ ./Android/Sdk/system-images/android-24`

Answer (score 11):

(Using the GUI, e.g. from Android Studio -> SDK Manager)

Check "Show Package Details" in the bottom-right corner, expand the "partially installed" SDK, uncheck the items you don't need, then press OK.